# Using an Async task to read from a filestream instead of an endless while loop

Tags: c#, filestream

Its a pretty simple program. I'm trying to read out messages from a controller after I send a message that requests constant messages to be sent back. The first part is how I managed to get the reading working as intended, and every time a message is sent I can see it in the Console. I want to recreate this scenario with the task in the code below that. How ever I haven't been successful in doing so.

```
            if (success)
            {
                if (fileStreamDeviceData.CanRead)
                {
                    while(success)
                    {
                        await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, outputReportBuffer.Length);
                        for (int b = 0; b < 12; b++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(outputReportBuffer[b] + " ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    }
                }
            }
```

So the above part works as intended except for the ugly endless while loop that is currently happening. The following 2 Code Parts are the solution for this, but its not working as intended and I don't seem to get anything out of it. I really suck with async tasks and stuff so maybe someone can help me fix the below section.

```
            if (success)
            {

                outputReportBuffer = null;
                //start async reading
                try
                {
                    outputReportBuffer = await ReadByteAsync();
                    for (int b = 0; b < outputReportBuffer.Length; b++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(outputReportBuffer[b] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }


    private async Task<Byte[]> ReadByteAsync()
    {
        Byte[] result = null;
        Byte[] outputReportBuffer = null;

        using (fileStreamDeviceData)
        {
            outputReportBuffer = new Byte[MyHid.Capabilities.OutputReportByteLength];

            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, outputReportBuffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                result = outputReportBuffer;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I get no exception or any output when I use this Code.

Comment: That first read loop is simply wrong; you aren't checking the **result** of the `ReadAsync` - it could legitimately return just 1 byte iteration if it wanted

Comment: You are simply updating a single buffer reference every loop iteration, assigning it each time to the same buffer. What is it you want to do when you read something?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You get no exception, but do you print anything to the console?

Comment: with the async task the while loop only triggers for the first report coming through, after that i dont receive anything else from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can be due to many reasons, try to print something int he while-loop first.

Does the caller `outputReportBuffer = await ReadByteAsync();` is inside an asyn method itself? If not I'll use `ReadByteAsync().Result` instead and set `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the `ReadByteAsync()` method.

```
    const int BufferSize = 100;

    private async Task<Byte[]> ReadByteAsync()
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (fileStreamDeviceData)
        {
            var outputReportBuffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
            int offset = 0;
            int byteRead;

            while ((byteRead = await fileStreamDeviceData.ReadAsync(outputReportBuffer, offset, outputReportBuffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(outputReportBuffer, offset, byteRead);
                offset += BufferSize;
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it is inside an async method, and as i mentioned above, the function only returns me the first and only the first message from the controller.

Comment: What is `fileStreamDeviceData` is that a stream? if so you must increment the offset in the while loop

Comment: that was the missing bit. without the increment of the offset i was spining in place

Comment: Can anyone tell: should it be *offset += byteRead;* ?    We just want to advance by the number of bytes read ?